# JSON Exception "Illegal value for primitive" obtained during response parsing

Tags: apex, json, rest

I am calling a Webservice which returns the following as JSON response.

```
**REST Response** :

{"totalRowCount":1,
"hasMorePages":false,
"data":[
        {
            "itemCode":"INC - 11819",
            "objectDataId":0,
            "objectName":"IncidentObject",
            "fields":[
                        {
                            "fieldName":"ActualIncidentDate",
                            "label":"Actual date and time this activity occurred",
                            "dataTypeName":"DATETIME",
                            "fields":null,                          
                            "subItems":null,
                            "values":[
                                        {"value":"Nov 10 2021  2:03PM"},
                                        {"value":""}
                                    ]
                        }
                    ]
        }
       ]
}
```

**Inner Classes**

```
global class values{
    global String value;
}

global class fields{
    global String fieldName;
    global String label;
    global String dataTypeName;
    global String fields;
    global String subItems;
    global List<values> values;
}

global class data{
    global String itemCode;
    global Integer objectDataId;
    global String objectName;
    global List<fields> fields;
}

global class incidentDetailLevel1{
    global Integer totalRowCount;
    //global Integer from_Z;
    //global Integer to_Z;
    global Boolean hasMorePages;
    global List<data> data;
}
```

I try to parse the JSON response as below

```
String formattedResponse = response.getBody(); 

        formattedResponse = formattedResponse.remove('"from":1,"to":1,');
        
         
        incidentDetailLevel1  detail =(incidentDetailLevel1 )JSON.deserialize(formattedResponse ,incidentDetailLevel1.class);
```

When I try that I get `System.JSONException: Illegal value for primitive`

Any ideas as to why I am getting this issue ?

The debug log does not provide me more info as to at what exact step the exception is thrown

I would appreciate if anyone can help me the mistake I have made in the classes built for storing the response or anything

UPDATE :

I have removed the "from" and "to" properties from the JSON response

Comment: Brief testing makes me think that this _shouldn't_ be the issue, but... `"totalRowCount":1`, `"from":1`, `"to":1`, and `"objectDataId":0` are all typed as integers in the JSON rather than as Strings. Does making those typed as Integers in your deserialization classes help at all?

Comment: Thanks Derek for your suggestion.. I changed the datatype from String to Integer  but the issue still remains and I get the exception

Comment: I even changed "hasMorePages" to Boolean but the issue still exists

Comment: Well, I copy-pasted your code to my org, dressed it up a bit, and it seems to work just fine. Maybe the problem is that the response isn't what you think it is?

Comment: @sfdcfox : yes the code works for some response and where as it gives me exception for some other instance..it is weird...in this particular incident it is fine.. will any special characters or anything in the HTTP response cause this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `JSON.deserialize` when there's property keys that are [reserved keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_reserved_words.htm) in Apex. If you got this code from [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com), make sure you use the "explicit parse" option, and use the `parse` method that's generated in order to parse your JSON correctly. In addition, you do need to make sure the data types match if you do this manually. I strongly suggest using a tool like json2apex to help you create the proper structures.

Comment: Thanks Brian appreciate it...I did create those classes manually by myself..I was aware of the reserved word conflict ("to" and "from") thats why i changed them to "to_Z" and "from_Z"..I am not aware of json2apex..will take a look at it also..Thanks mate

Comment: @KVN Yeah, the `_Z` convention comes from json2apex, I think. `JSON.deserialize` won't automatically convert the properties as you expect, so you have to go with explicit parsing.

Comment: hi Brian..I have removed the "from" and "to" properties from the JSON response itself but still it is causing the exception..Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the data are not coming in string, so once you change the data type of those in your class the issue will be resolved.

> totalRowCount":Integer

> "from":Integer

> "to":Integer

> "hasMorePages":Boolean

> "objectDataId":Integer

Make sure you are not missing any of those.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my comment, and a quick test with anonymous apex ruled out this being an issue.

Comment: Are you testing for the same response ? Probably the "fields" is currently null. But the data will come in list for some other request. Just like for values, it is coming in list.